# git tags are not recognized anymore

Tags: git, git-tag, git-describe

I got a weird problem with my git repository. It suddently "stopped" working with tags. I can create tags, i can list tags. I can even use `git checkout $tag` or `git logs $tag`. But when using `git describe --exact-match` the tag is not detected anymore? This currently breaks my pipeline, since the tagged commit on master seems to be not tagged to git itself? One week ago it was working flawlessly.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git tag my-test-tag
$ git describe --exact-match
fatal: no tag exactly matches '4b2aa1dcf70eaf61640e6a983df82e1ffe3a5812'
```

I already tried running `git fsck --full` which only fixed some dangling commits, which looked fine for me (since i'm rebasing quite a lot).

Another funny thing: The tool `gitg` is not showing any history for these "new" commits. While for "old" commits everything works as expected.

Anybody got a clue what is going on here?

Tested on 3 machines, all running git version 2.17.1.

Comment: `git tag` creates a non-annotated tag by default (use `-a` to change this) and `git describe` refers only to annotated tags by default (use `--all` or `--tags` to change this), so the output quoted above is not terribly surprising.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I normally tag my commits via Commandline and always add the `-a`. But this time i created the tag via GitLab and if you leave out the "message" field, you implicitly create a un-annotated tag.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html#create-a-new-tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git tag` creates a non-annotated tag by default;
use `-a` to change this.

`git describe` refers only to annotated tags by default;
use `--all` or `--tags` to change this.

*This answer was originally [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562335/git-tags-are-not-recognized-anymore/61182221#comment101586407_57562335) by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)*